# starting docker container with host mount to container

Tags: docker

I am beginner and just started using  docker, before posting here I google a lot but a lot of mixed confusing result.

I started docker with this command

```
docker run -itd --name dockWeb2 -v /var/www/wordpress/ -p 80:80  atozchevara/rpi-apache-php5
```

hoping I would be able to directly mount wordpress installation onto container , as by default it picks internal path of container `/var/www/index.php`, to override it I used `-v` flag. but it doesn't work.

I tried using multiple ports by passing `-p` arguments again for each port but that too gives error
`docker run -itd --name dockWeb3 -v /var/www/wordpress/ -p 80:80  -p 22:22 atozchevara/rpi-apache-php5`

`66a959e4e99af8122705913005fcae12e2e8a5203da7b77ff1717751314fca28
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dockWeb3 (eb42a619a8c79961d35d59e0d8930a92541a20132525055afb3b0d2d87483e7f): Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated.`

otherwise Could have uploaded  my wordpress using ssh to container's `/var/www/` location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first issue if you want to mount a volume from the host you need to use `Bind mount a volume`

```
docker run -itd --name dockWeb2 -v your_project_path:/var/www/wordpress/ 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated.  atozchevara/rpi-apache-php5
```

For the post using `-p 80:80`  you are publishing container port 80 to the host port 80, and if the host port is already in use you got an error `0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated.` try to use a different port `-p 9090:80.`

Comment: hang on a sec, I referred `/var/www/wordpress/` to the path on host machine on which docker is running, do you mean the path `your_project_path` is container internal path ?

Comment: lets say you have a wordpress directory on your machine exp `"/home/amine/wordpress"` and you want the  wordpress dir to be mounted on your docker container in the path `/var/www/wordpress` , so simply you need to use `-v "/home/amine/wordpress:/var/www/wordpress` i hope this will clear things for you

Comment: for the second post, I am not using -p 80:80 twice, first I used `-p 80:80` then i used `-p 22:22` for `ssh` which means ports are different not the same so in that case how port is already allocated ?

Comment: you're already using the port 80 by another  programme check your allocated ports or  use a different port

Comment: Before using it I `docker stop` all my running containers